# Unauthenticated with the guard (session)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, postman

I don't need to use a token to authenticate but I am building a REST API. I made a custom guard to use the session with basic auth. When I try to authenticate from postman it always shows unauthenticated. When I try to login in 'php artisan tinker' with a 'user instance', it works. My questions are the following.

---

1. When I log in from Tinker using 'Auth::login($user)', does it keep
   the session?
2. Why is the authentication not working from the code provided below?
3. Between API (api.php) and Web (web.php) routes which one is executed first?
4. When I use postman basic auth do I have to provide just a normal password like 'admin' or does it have to be a hashed password?

---

**Auth.php**

```php
'api' => [
    'driver' => 'session',
    'provider' => 'users',
]
```

**API Routes**

```php
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1', 'middleware' => ['auth:admin', 'admin']], function () {
    Route::get('/users/check', 'v1\UserController@userOnlineStatus');
    Route::resource('/users', v1\UserController::class)->except([
        'create', 'edit'
    ]);
});
```

**Web Routes**

```php
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/{any}', 'SinglePageController@index')->where('any', '.*');
```